# Jquery javascript ajax - price total not updating

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I am trying to get this code below to work with updating a price based on an ajax onclick:

```
$('#main_body li[data-pricefield="special"]').delegate('onclick','change', function(e)
{
    var temp = $(this).attr("id").split('_');
    var element_id = temp[1];

    var pricedef = $(this).data('pricedef');
    if(pricedef == null)
    {
        pricedef = 0;
    }

    $("#li_" + element_id).data("pricevalue",pricedef);
    calculate_total_payment();
});
```

Things seem to be working ok so far - when I type in the console:

```
jQuery('#li_273').data('pricevalue');
```

I do get a value of "1.00" returned which is actually being set here on the onclick command:

```
'onclick' => 'jQuery(\'#li_273\').data(\'pricevalue\',\'1.00\');',
```

My question is what is wrong with my first block of code that is stopping this from calculating the price the right way and how do I correct it?

Comment: Two questions: 1) are you sure your delegate function is firing?  2) Where do you set `pricedef`?

Comment: When you say what is stopping it calculating the 'right way' - what's it actually doing that's wrong?

Comment: You need to specify a selector `.delegate('onclick'` <-- should be a selector.. I'm sure you have no `onclick` elements

Comment: @Kyle - the opening tag: <li id="li_273" data-pricefield="special" data-pricevalue="0" > and how can I check for certain if the delegate is firing? Ben - The price should be updating on the main page

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.

Comment: $('#main_body li[data-pricefield="special"]').delegate('li','change', function(e) { actually works when you tab out of the field - it adds the $1 to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
$('#main_body li[data-pricefield="special"]').delegate('onclick','change', function(e){
   // ...
});
```

but `delegate`'s syntax is `.delegate( selector, eventType, handler(eventObject) )` and in this case you should write

```
$('#main_body').delegate('li[data-pricefield="special"]','click', function(e){
   // ...
});
```

There is no `onclick` event in `jQuery` and AFAIK an `li` doesn't have a `change` event so if you want to use multiple events then you can use

```
$('#main_body').delegate('li[data-pricefield="special"]','click another_event', function(e){
   // ...
});
```

Also you can use `on` instead of `delegate`.

[**An Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/q7GhH/) and [**Read more**](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

Comment: The only thing I could think of is if he fired custom "change" and "onclick" events somehow...but that seems unlikely given the rest of it.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, thanks! Yes it could be but in this case, multiple events should be placed in the second argument separating by a space in side quotes.

Comment: @Sheikh - thank you so much - that seemed to have fixed the issue. While things are still hard coded for price - it is however adding the price to the total correctly! Thanks again!

Comment: Any chance how we can update another field (text box) showing a value of 1 when that event happens?

Answer (score 1):

'onclick', 'change' should be 'click change' in the delegate

EDIT: "$('#main_body li[data-pricefield="special"]').delegate('li','change', function(e) { actually works when you tab out of the field - it adds the $1 to it."

so you should have:

```
$('#main_body li[data-pricefield="special"]').on('li','click change', function(e) {
```

and perhaps check

```
if(pricedef == undefined || pricedef == null){
```

Comment: I might get a better answer with some markup, but I guessed a bit

Comment: This is likely your markup that I guessed at and this selector might be the better hook for that `$('#main_body').on('li[data-pricefield="special"]',`